# Как проверить условие IF с оператором IN в результатах SELECT?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Пытаюсь проверить, существует ли значение в результатах запроса `SELECT`.

Знаю, что можно сделать что-то вроде:

```
IF var IN ('A', 'B') THEN 
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('True');
END IF;
```

Но хотел бы сделать что-то вроде:

```
IF var IN (SELECT x FROM DUAL) THEN 
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('True');
END IF;
```

Есть ли синтаксически правильный способ сделать это?

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [IF Statement Using IN Operator On SELECT Results](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69214994) от участника [@Acroyear](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2227422/acroyear)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/69214994

Answer (score 2):

Вызвать запрос в операторе `IN` возможно в SQL, но в PL/SQ это синтаксически неверно.

Запрос можно вызвать до оператора `IF ... THEN`, который и проверит результат запроса:

```
declare
    var char (1) := 'x';
    found int;
begin
    select count(*) into found from t where val = var and rownum=1;
    if found = 1 then
        dbms_output.put_line (var||' Found');
    end if;
end;
```

> x Found

Где `found` примет значение 1 - найдено, а 0 - не найдено.

Обратите внимание, что с предикатом `rownum=1` запрос сразу же закончится, как только будет найдено одно первое совпадение для значения `var`, что полностью соответствует логике работы оператора `IN`.